# I need help for a submit form in react js

Tags: reactjs

I do a video tutorial from Dev Ed. https://youtu.be/35lXWvCuM8o
It's a movie list. The  should submit a new movie.
The counter at the top is rising as hitting the submit button.
But only blank   are created. I miss something. I don't see the error.

Here is the repository for the project: https://bitbucket.org/limesquirrel/dev_ed_react_tutorials/src/master/Videos%20React%20Router%2C%20State%20Management%2C%20Redux/02%20State%20Management/statemanagement-tut/

Those are the files:
I only use files in the ./src/ directory.

[App.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX4EX.jpg)

[AddMovie.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk86f.jpg)

[Inspector output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMr1s.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question and my answer might be helpful to you.
I see you haven't called your movies variable anywhere in the function or might have called it with a wrong name.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in shape

```
 setMovies([...prevMovies,{name:name; price:price}])
```

Good luck